# Raking weights - How can they possibly recover the joint distribution?

Tags: survey, weights, survey-sampling, survey-weights

So I've recently encountered raking weights as a way to obtain weights for population level estimates: https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/2018/01/26/how-different-weighting-methods-work/.

My question is how can these possibly recover the joint distribution for two variables? For example, say we know the marginal distribution for sex: 50% and 50%. Also say that we know that the marginal distribution for and with several discrete categories (e.g., Under 40 years, 40 to 80 years, and over 80 years) is: 40%, 40%, and 20%. I know these numbers are wonky and made up but hang with me for this hypothetical scenario. Also, assume that we don't know the joint distribution of sex and age from something like the U.S. Census Bureau and we need to estimate the joint distribution of age and sex to get population weights.

If you assume that age and sex are independent, then it's clear how to get the weights. But, we know that they're not independent (there are more elderly women than men), so from what I understand raking weights are a way to estimate the weights for a joint distribution of sex and age.

**Bottom line question:** How can literally any method - including raking weights - take marginal distributions of two correlated variables and produce good estimates? It seems like these weights can possibly account for the correlation between age and sex, right?